# Problem with drawing custom Windows controls

Tags: windows, winapi, themes, custom-controls, gdi

I'm playing around with drawing my own custom controls using the uxTheme library in Windows, and I can't work out why my control doesn't look like the regular Windows control that (supposedly) uses the same theme I'm using:

[image: A Windows ComboBox and my control that uses the ComboBox theme]

The above image shows a standard Windows ComboBox (top) and my custom control drawn using the ComboBox theme (bottom).  What I can't work out is why the border from my control is a different shape and colour to the standard control.

In my class constructor I open the theme data:

```
mComboTheme = OpenThemeData( hwnd, L"COMBOBOX" );
```

And then in the handler for WM_PAINT I'm just drawing two parts of the ComboBox components:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC         hdc;
    RECT        client;

    if( GetUpdateRect( hwnd, &ps.rcPaint, false ))
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );
        GetClientRect( hwnd, &client );

        if( IsThemeBackgroundPartiallyTransparent( mComboTheme, CP_BACKGROUND, CBXS_HOT ))
        {
            DrawThemeParentBackground( hwnd, hdc, &ps.rcPaint );
        }
        DrawThemeBackground( mComboTheme, hdc, CP_BACKGROUND, CBXS_HOT, &client, &ps.rcPaint );
        client.left = client.right - 20;
        DrawThemeBackground( mComboTheme, hdc, CP_DROPDOWNBUTTONRIGHT, CBXSR_HOT, &client, ps.rcPaint );

        EndPaint( *this, &ps );
    }
    break;
}
```

Any suggestions as to why these two controls don't look the same would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

James

Comment: it's not much worse anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You called `DrawThemeBackground` with `CP_BACKGROUND` and `CP_DROPDOWNBUTTONRIGHT`. Perhaps you should also call it with `CP_BORDER` if you want the border to match the standard combobox?

Comment: Hah!  Yes, that was the rather obvious point I was missing.  Thanks.  :)